# Storing / calculating historical load averages

Tags: linux, performance, performance-monitoring, uptime, load-average

When I run `uptime`, I get output similar to the following:

```
 07:50:39 up 13 days,  5:00,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.02, 0.00
```

Is there a way, other than by running `uptime` every X-many minutes, to get a more historical load average?

I'd like to be able to graph the load averages across the last week, month, etc.

Perhaps I'm looking in the wrong place?

**Update**
I can't choose between [collectd](http://collectd.org/) (@[david spillet](https://serverfault.com/users/5221/david-spillett)) or [munin](http://munin.projects.linpro.no/) (@[icapan](https://serverfault.com/users/7651/icapan)) - so for now, I'll use both (on different machines).

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

I use [collectd](http://collectd.org/) to record system load amongst a number of other parameters. It stores the data in [RRD](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/) stores that can be graphed and otherwise analysed using the many available tools and scripts. I use a modified version of [this script](http://haroon.sis.utoronto.ca/rrd/scripts/) for my graphing ([sample output](http://haroon.sis.utoronto.ca/cgi-bin/rrd.cgi/)).

Collectd has plugins for monitoring lots of stuff (everything commonly asked for and a few things on top), and creating your own shouldn't be difficult if you need something specialised, so makes for a very flexible tool. Configuring the graphs in rrd.cgi is a very manual process, though not difficult, though you might well find a more convenient tool for working with the RRD files maintained by collectd.

Comment: that looks pretty cool - will definitely look at it as an option :)

Answer (score 5):

[Munin](http://munin.projects.linpro.no/) is the easiest way to get uptime graphs with minimum effort in installing and configuring. 
I also use atop for aggregate cpu usage by some process, but that is not what You asked for.

Comment: Yes, Munin is nice and it's extremely easy to write your own plugin, too.

Comment: I'll check this one out, too

Answer (score 2):

Look at `man sadc` (System activity data collector) and `man sar` (Collect, report, or save system activity information).

On my Ubuntu system, all I had to do to enable data collections, since the `cron` job was already in place, was edit `/etc/default/sysstat` and change this line to "true":

```
ENABLED="true"
```

To display load information similar to `uptime`, do:

```
sar -q
```

To display default output for a particular time range and date (here, the 20th of the month):

```
sar -s 11:00:00 -e 14:00:00 -f /var/log/sysstat/sa20
```

Comment: thanks @Dennis - but collectd and munin are closer to what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Load average data can be found in `/proc/loadavg` pseudo-file. The format there is maybe more suitable for an automatic processing. Apart from the format, these are exactly the same numbers as those you receive when you execute the `uptime` command.

Once ago, to solve a problem similar to yours, I just scheduled a bash script with `cron` to read `/proc/loadavg` and issue a `rrdtool update` command to update a RRD database.

Comment: running cron every minute would certainly work, but I'm hoping to accomplish this without something so.. laborious :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [atop](https://www.atoptool.nl/) in combination with [atopsar-plot](https://codeberg.org/mgellner/atopsar-plot).
Install both tools:

```
sudo apt install atop
pip install -U git+https://codeberg.org/mgellner/atopsar-plot
```

Then use it like this:

```
atopsar-plot --day 2024-02-06 --disk vda --iface eth0
```

Historical resource usage graphs look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dCMT.png). Full disclosure: I'm the author of atopsar-plot.