# What is system load?

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to understand the memory usage and load average in linux server](https://serverfault.com/questions/67759/how-to-understand-the-memory-usage-and-load-average-in-linux-server)

I was reading [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/284828/how-high-can-system-load-go), and it left me wondering what system load is. What does it actually measure?

Comment: This question has been asked before, and there are several duplicates. Additionally the answer is found in several of the answers and comments under question **you** linked.

Answer (score 0):

It measures the inability for processes to get their slice of the CPU pie in a timely manner.