# What is "normal" server load?

Tags: ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Acceptable load average](https://serverfault.com/questions/63319/acceptable-load-average)

My Ubuntu server's load is 5-7 most of the times. When the load is about 7 and I check my server response at [webpagetest.org](http://www.webpagetest.org/) I get an F grade (~9 Sec) for 'First Byte Load' while when load is about 4, I usually get A grade for FBL. So I suspect 7 should be an unacceptably high load. Now wondering what range of server loads are generally regarded as normal?

Comment: There is no "normal" without knowing more about the server and what it's supposed to do for a living.  I have an Ubuntu 10 machine serving up 8 websites with about 1500 views a day per site along with file storage, internal dns that shows about 5% use *per day* - I almost never see 7% load unless updates are running or a backup is being performed.  Run htop and watch what is causing the highest load.

Comment: It's not a duplicate: 'How high server load go?' is logically a different question.

Comment: @user88597 Let's put it this way: What figures of server load should be alarming?

Comment: @James Cpu usage is usually over %70. RAM usage around 7GB.

Comment: oops, meant to edit my previous comment (I accidentally deleted it). How much RAM do you have, and how many cpu cores do you have?

Comment: @James The total RAM is 8GB. The cpu has 4 cores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how many CPU or Core you have

2 CPU > 2

4 CPU > 4

2 Core > 2

4 Core > 4

2 CPU (EACH 4 CORE) > 8

4 CPU (EACH 4 CORE) > 16

Comment: My CPU is Xeon quad core, so at least for me your measures make sense. As I mentioned, at  load < 4 I don't have delayed first byte problem.

Comment: Tweak sysctl.conf, If it's a php web server, use MPM apache, fastcgi, Tune MYSQL. it has a great effect.

Comment: Ali, can you elaborate on sysctl.conf please?

Comment: this is what I use: [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/300882/sysctl-optimized)